# Select column matching string name dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm attempting to create a function that uses `dplyr` inside of it. However, I can't quite seem to figure out how to select a column from a `data.frame`. I'm trying to do something like this example:

```
test_df <- data.frame(A=1:30)
my_function <- function(x, var){
    x %>%
        summarize(my_mean = mean(var))
}
my_function(test_df, "A")
```

Which produces this error:

Warning message:
In mean.default("A") : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to fix this, is to subset from `.`:

```
my_function <- function(x, var){
    x %>%
        summarize(my_mean = mean(.[[var]]))
}
```

Comment: Thanks; so simple! Should've thought of this one myself....